# How to manually create JSON object for GMail API ('Message' object)

Tags: gmail-api, filemaker

I'm trying to create a system for creating and sending emails through the GMail API.  I have gotten a receive workflow working (Oauth, retrieves and parses emails).  So I have seen the 'Message' JSON objects that Google uses.

Now I want to send out a 'Message' that was created by my system.  So I'm looking for information about what is the minimal or basic set of elements needed to create a valid 'Message' object for Google's GMail API.

My platform is using FileMaker Pro... so I can't really use any existing library for their templates and functions.  I am looking to build the JSON object directly, with text functions.

I have seen the GMail API documentation.  It doesn't really seem to clarify what is required or optional.  One side point:  Message ID - it doesn't describe the parameters for that.  Can I set it to anything I want? Is that something only generated as a PK for Google's own database to store it under?  (Apparently it's not required, as it seems it will be defined and returned in the Send response.)

I note that it has the 'Raw' element... maybe it's simpler to build the RFC 2822 text from a template of some sort, doing targeted replacements?  It still is a matter of - what's minimally needed in the template?  (Would eventually like to be able to send attachments, too.)  And it seems that building a JSON object version would be more readable, maintainable, and/or robust.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Please formulate your question in terms of input, required logic and expected output. Note that Filemaker has dedicated functions for creating JSON output from its data, so there is no need (and you would be ill-advised) to create it using text functions - see: https://help.claris.com/en/pro-help/content/json-functions-category.html

Comment: Right, I'm using the included JSON functions.

Comment: Grr... comment time limit... here's the rest:  The 'manual' part is that I'm not using 3rd party library.  So I'm trying to figure out which 'Message' JSON elements are required.  E.g. 'Payload.Raw' is required.  (Odd - the 'Raw' value , RFC2822 compliant content, duplicates many/all the 'Message' JSON elements.)  I got far enough that I have a JSON object that fails in my Insert From URL step (Error 400 - Recipient required...), but it WORKS went sent via their 'Try this API' widget (API docs page).  So what cURL headears are required?  I probably have something wrong there.